# SQLite order by date

Tags: sql, sqlite

My date is not in standard form. This is how it is: 07/15/2013 06:53:05 and is stored as string in the database.
How can I query it to order it by date.

This query is not working.

```
SELECT jobno, ondate FROM Reports ORDER BY DATE(ondate)
```

When I run this query it orders it alphabetically and not date wise.

Comment: The term, not working, is too vague to allow others to help you.  What happens when you run that query?

Comment: Only save timestamps. Always.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written here, [SQLite doesn't have a date type](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html), so you can do this:

```
SELECT jobno, ondate
FROM Reports
ORDER BY substr(ondate,7)||substr(ondate,1,2)||substr(ondate,4,2)
```

[<kbd>sql fiddle demo</kbd>](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/979d5/1)

Comment: I am also facing one more problem. Can you guide me.
I want the most recent date from each group. My brain is not working and I have to complete the project and its 4am here and I am working like a zombie.

Comment: @coding Post a different/new question. I suggest some sleep, but for "max/min per group", see those aggregate functions :>

Answer (score 1):

This is why this format is *not* a recommend date/time storage mechanism in SQLite.

You can use [`strftime`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) to covert the data into something that can be well-ordered (note that we just have to specify the American-ish format string), e.g.

```
SELECT jobno, ondate FROM Reports
ORDER BY strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S', ondate)
```

However, **this approach (as well as the approach in the other answer) will *not* be able to use indices and *performance on large data may suffer***!

From [SQLite Datatypes: 1.2 Date and Time Datatype](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) the advice is:

> SQLite does not have a storage class set aside for storing dates and/or times. Instead, the built-in Date And Time Functions of SQLite are capable of storing dates and times as TEXT, REAL, or INTEGER values:
>
> - TEXT as ISO8601 strings ("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS").
> - REAL as Julian day numbers, the number of days since noon in Greenwich on November 24, 4714 B.C. according to the proleptic Gregorian calendar.
> - INTEGER as Unix Time, the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.

I *recommend* using [ISO 8601](https://xkcd.com/1179/) as it's still human-readable, is well-understood (and culture neutral), can encode the TZ (just be consistent!), and can be indexed well.

Comment: Somehow this did not worked when I tried to order it in desc..!! I also tried on the fiddle provided by Roman Pekar.

Comment: @coding Whoops. I used `'%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S'` when it *should* have been `'%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S'`. Note the separators. I've corrected it now, so it should work - try it just to get familiar with it, although both approaches don't fix the fundamental issue (they merely work around it).